# Attaching items to the pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble finding tutorials/demos on how to make items follow the pointer. Here are some examples site `www.joyride.city` , `www.jeremytill.net`.

Comment: what's the problem man ? elaborate please

Comment: I would like to recreate a similar effect on a bootstrap project. However, I have no idea where to begin. I was hoping to find a tutorial to waltkthrough.

Comment: Maybe a better question is, how can an object follow the pointer around the screen? See joyride.city as an example, where the pointer is dragging polygon shapes around. I have noticed this effect does not transpire on to mobile devices.